# Raspberry Pi send 3.3v signal for 100ms

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am working on a Image Classifier which will work on a RPi and after classifying the image from a camera it will need to send two 3.3v signals form two different GPIO pins for 100ms (based on the image classification).

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help and feel free to ask me more if needed.

Comment: Essentially it is no different from flashing an LED or two https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/4

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: So I just choose any GPIO pin and set it to ON for 100ms? That's it?

Comment: That seems to me to match what your question asked... yes. I presume you will need a resistor somewhere to limit the current flow but that's it from the software side and maybe a voltage shifter.

Comment: Yeah well I only need to work on the software side, one last question: 
In the link you sent me it says LED(17) for example. Isn't there something more general? Or it does not matter even if it says LED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

led_pin = 17

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)

for _ in range(2):
    GPIO.output(led_pin, True)
    sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.output(led_pin, False)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Or setup more easily

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(17)

for _ in range(2):
    led.on()
    sleep(0.1)
    led.off()
    sleep(0.1)
```